# iPhone keyboard scan codes for screen brightness

Tags: iphone, keyboard, arduino, scancodes

I am trying to adjust the screen brightness of an iPhone from my `Arduino`, which is acting like a keyboard. Unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful because I don't know the exact scan codes to send.

I checked out [ApplePS2Keyboard.cpp](http://opensource.apple.com/source/ApplePS2Keyboard/ApplePS2Keyboard-3/ApplePS2Keyboard.cpp) and found that `0x69 (brightness down)` and `0x6A (brightness up)` **only work on my Mac**, but those scan codes do not work on the iPhone for some reason.

I also thought about using a key combo of `Fn+F1`, but it seems like `Fn` does not generate any scan code, so I was not able to proceed.

***[Update 12/11/2012]: Downloaded the KeyCodes app and ran it on my Mac, and it looks like the `Fn` key generates a modifier of `0x800100`, but the "Brightness Up" function key does not generate any key code. Does it mean that the scan code `0x6A` is received by the kernel and then immediately translated into an action instead of a key code?***

***If Apple's wireless keyboard works on both the Mac and any iOS device, and assuming that it generates the same scan codes no matter which host you pair it with, why would the same scan code not work on the iOS device?***

I've already tried using brute-force by looping through possible scan codes from `0x2A to 0x80`, but none of them works. I've also tried brute-forcing all permutations of the Consumer Report format, but that didn't work either. My bluetooth module is Roving Networks RN-42 HID.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever get this working?